# How to align one of two div columns

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble aligning the left column of two columns. I want them to appear responsively in the center of the page.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VzJg.jpg)

Here is my current code:

```
    <div style="background: url('http://www.house-for-fast-cash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/houses-background.jpg')">
<center><h2>WE BUY HOUSES Any Reason, Any Condition</h2></center>
<div style="width: 100%">
        <div style="width: 50%; float: left; display: inline-block; ">
          <ul>
            <li>Behind on taxes</li>
            <li>Behind in Payment</li>
            <li>Vacant / Vandalized</li>
            <li> Inheritance</li>
            <li>Expire Listing </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
            <ul>
              <li>Bad Tenant</li>
              <li>Facing Foreclosure</li>
              <li>Divorce</li>
              <li>Tired Landlord</li>
              <li>Fire Damage</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<center><h2><strong><a href="http://www.house-for-fast-cash.com/contact/">Get Me An Offer RIGHT AWAY!</a></strong><strong></h2></center>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Clare

Comment: try to add on `first div` `text-align:right;` or `float:right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNRpoo

If you want the first list to be aligned along the bullet marks, you have to put it in an additional wrapper which you make `display: inline-block` like this and in which you align the text to the left again:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jryYxW

Comment: You totally rock - this works beautifullly. Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the first div like this

```
<div style="width: 50%; text-align:right; display: inline-block; ">
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications this is possible:

```
<div style="background: url('http://www.house-for-fast-cash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/houses-background.jpg')">
<center><h2>WE BUY HOUSES Any Reason, Any Condition</h2>
<div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;">
        <div style="width: 50%; float: left; display: inline-block; ">
          <ul>
            <li>Behind on taxes</li>
            <li>Behind in Payment</li>
            <li>Vacant / Vandalized</li>
            <li> Inheritance</li>
            <li>Expire Listing </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
            <ul>
              <li>Bad Tenant</li>
              <li>Facing Foreclosure</li>
              <li>Divorce</li>
              <li>Tired Landlord</li>
              <li>Fire Damage</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<h2><strong><a href="http://www.house-for-fast-cash.com/contact/">Get Me An Offer RIGHT AWAY!</a></strong><strong></h2></center>
</div>
```

Note the `display:inline-block;` which cause the `DIV` to be only as wide as it needs to be, and therefore it can be centered.

It is better to put the styles seperate from your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Set `text-align` to `center` in outer div and `display` to `inline`, `text-align` to `left` in both inner div elements.

Here is the working code.

```html
<div style="background: url('http://www.house-for-fast-cash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/houses-background.jpg'); ">
<center><h2>WE BUY HOUSES Any Reason, Any Condition</h2></center>
<div style=" text-align: center;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
          <ul>
            <li>Behind on taxes</li>
            <li>Behind in Payment</li>
            <li>Vacant / Vandalized</li>
            <li> Inheritance</li>
            <li>Expire Listing </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
            <ul>
              <li>Bad Tenant</li>
              <li>Facing Foreclosure</li>
              <li>Divorce</li>
              <li>Tired Landlord</li>
              <li>Fire Damage</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<center><h2><strong><a href="http://www.house-for-fast-cash.com/contact/">Get Me An Offer RIGHT AWAY!</a></strong><strong></h2></center>
</div>
```